# Error message: `composer_install` had stderr output

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, composer-php

I'm deploying a Laravel application to a Google App Engine Standard environment but I'm getting a PHP composer error due to dependencies issues at the moment I'm doing a `gcloud app deploy`.

I have followed all the instructions on this Google's tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard) but they haven't had any troubleshooting section to explained about this

This is the error I'm getting on the terminal after `gcloud app deploy`:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 245bdb05-2dfa-4fe6-bdca-5e3e99221de1 status: FAILURE.
Error ID: 990D4641.
Error type: InternalError.
Error message: `composer_install` had stderr output:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for ext-protobuf 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by ext-protobuf[3.7.0].
    - google/gax 1.0.0 conflicts with ext-protobuf[3.7.0].
    - Installation request for google/gax 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by google/gax[1.0.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

error: `composer_install` returned code: 2.
```

Here's my app.yaml:

```
env_variables:
    ## Put production environment variables here.
    APP_KEY: [my_app_key]
    APP_STORAGE: /tmp
    VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
    CACHE_DRIVER: database
    SESSION_DRIVER: database
    ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
    DB_DATABASE: [my_db]
    DB_USERNAME: root
    DB_PASSWORD: [my_super_secure_password]
    DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/test-project]:us-east1:test-db"
    LOG_CHANNEL: stackdriver
```

I need to be able to deploy the application without this PHP composer errors within the Google App Engine standard environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing and enabling the missing packages using PECL

[Cloud.google.com grpc](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc)

Comment: Based on what I have shared, how did you get that the **grpc** extension was missing?

Comment: Your error log stated ext-protobuf. Searched for ext-protobuf google cloud php think it came up with the info I provided.